# How can I get this code to only smooth scroll only the elements I want?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a smooth scroll code which works great, the problem is it works too well. I have other elements that use "#" is the  tag(example:  but I don't want the tabs to be targeted by the smooth scroll. I have the following smooth scroll code:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($)  {
       $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
  if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
   var target = $(this.hash);
   target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
    if (target.length) {
       $('html,body').animate({
       scrollTop: target.offset().top
     }, 1000);
     return false;
   }
 }
});
});
```

Is there anyway to modify this to only target the anchors for the page an not tab anchors

Comment: Hello Mike, quick question: when you say you want 'target anchors' to be targeted and not the 'tab anchors', do you mean that you have a menu with tabs in it, and the javascript function scrolls the user to that menu tab anchor instead of wherever the other anchor you want is?

Comment: Hi @NachoDawg , yes I have a menu with tabs that I do not want that smooth scroll to target. What happens is that when I click on the tabs it does the smooth scroll animation, which I don't want on that tabs

Comment: I'm not sure if I get it. The intended functionality is to click on a tab, and the website should scroll down to the corresponding anchor below? What should the user click, then what should happen? Could you possibly edit your question to add the HTML  for us to look at?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to affect links with `#` as href value the syntax you should use looks like this:

```
$("[attribute!='value']")
```

So in your case you specify `href` as attribute and `#` as value.

```
$("a[href!='#']").on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //do stuff
});
```

Comment: When I add that in it still targets the tabs that I do not want it to target

Comment: you should probably explain which ones not to target more specifically. YOu could just give them a class and specify this class in the selector.